# How do I get a `NuGetFramework` that represents the current framework?

Tags: c#, nuget

I am trying to parse a nuget file to find which lib subfolder I should use to bring the referenced dlls in a project.

My approach is to find all instances which are compatible with the currently running framework.

While below compiles and runs the possible list is never filled. I think this is because the `current` instance isn't correct, as it has the version `0.0.0.0`.

This means the comparer doesn't work.

*So how do I get a NuGetFramework for the current framework?*

```
using var packageReader = new PackageArchiveReader(packageStream);

var current = new NuGetFramework(RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription);

foreach (var i in packageReader.GetSupportedFrameworks())
{
  if (DefaultCompatibilityProvider.Instance.IsCompatible(i, current))
  {
    possible.Add(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will return the correct `NuGetFramework` instance.

```cs
    private static NuGetFramework GetCurrentFramework() =>
    NuGetFramework.Parse(
        Assembly
            .GetEntryAssembly()?
            .GetCustomAttribute<TargetFrameworkAttribute>()?
            .FrameworkName ?? throw new Exception("Cannot determine the current version of .net")
    );
```